# how to dynamically fetch graph ql content

Tags: reactjs, server, graphql, get, apollo

I am building something like an ecommerce website where the user can add products to a cart. Later when the user visits the cart page or the mini-cart popup, the products they added need to show up there. I am saving the products the user adds on the frontend as an array of product ids. How do i build a fetching schema which will fetch the products based on the array of ids. I cannot POST on the server so I cannot save the cart content there. I use Apollo to manage the API. Below is the link to the repo of the project and I would be incredibly grateful if someone could help me.

https://github.com/robertobadzo/scandiweb

Comment: You can dynamically construct an API query which returns the product IDs of concern. Apollo docs: https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/how-to-filter-and-search-using-variables-in-apollo-client/

If you're trying to store the array of product IDs in global state, consider React Context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: I think this requires updating the server-side code, but I cannot mess up with the server side, only on the front-end

Comment: A bit hacky as it enforces inconsistencies if you use more than one tab but you could store the selected ids in the [local storage](https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react/). On page load you retrieve them again and use them as input params for your query. You have to make sure that you keep the local storage consistent with the actual page.